# How do server snapshots work when databases or files change frequently?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean, snapshot

When using a "snapshot" feature in Google Cloud Platform or Digital Ocean, how does this work when a database or file is being updated in the middle of the snapshot?

For example, if a log file or database is updated frequently, is it possible that the snapshot would copy that file (capture a snapshot) mid-write or possibly a corrupt version?

Can I rely on snapshots to get an older version of a database, if this database is updated many times per second?

Answer (score 0):

What you call "snapshots", in a DigitalOcean context, I assume to mean "backups". DigitalOcean's "snapshots" requires powering down. DO's backups, however, are live. They have a great article describing how it works, with an interesting chunk quoted below. I can't speak to GCP, but I assume it would be similar.

> A crash-consistent backup allows the system to capture all of the data
>   on disk exactly as it was at a single point in time. This means that
>   the data will be backed up in a consistent state.
>
> This is called a crash-consistent backup because it saves every piece
>   of data that was committed to the disk at the moment of that the
>   snapshot occurs. The data saved is consistent with the data that would
>   be available if the system crashed at that exact point and had to
>   recover on boot.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-digitalocean-droplet-backups

Comment: Snapshots don't require a shut-off anymore :) so curious how it works as the data changes mid-backup.